# Can I reference an object using a string?

Tags: excel, vba

So my code looks like this:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim labelnum As String

For i = 1 To 81
    labelnum = "Label" & i
    If "labelnum".Caption = Label1.Caption Then
    "labelnum".BackColor = Label1.BackColor
    End If
Next i
```

I want to loop through 81 labels to check to see if the caption in that one is the same as the one I have selected. Is there something else I can put where it says "labelnum"?

I'm practicing and trying to make sudoku through VBA. I want to highlight the box I have selected and highlight all other squares on the board that have the same number.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at CallByName function in VBA https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/calling-a-property-or-method-using-a-string-name

Comment: What type of "Labels" are you using? - Are they 1) ActiveX objects on a worksheet, 2) Form Controls on a worksheet, or 3) Objects on a user form?

Comment: And FWIW you can't "Select" `Label`s.  Maybe you are using `TextBox`s?

Answer (score 1):

In a Worksheet, a Label is a `Shape` Object, so you can use the `Shapes` collection:

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim shpLabel As Shape

For i = 1 To 81
    Set shpLabel = Sheet1.Shapes("labelnum" & i)
    If shpLabel.Caption = Label1.Caption Then
        shpLabel.BackColor = Label1.BackColor
    End If
    Set shpLabel = Nothing
Next i
```

In a UserForm, a Label is a `Control` Object, so you can use the `Controls` collection:

```vb
Dim i As Integer
Dim ctrlLabel As Control

For i = 1 To 81
    Set ctrlLabel = Me.Controls("labelnum" & i)
    If ctrlLabel.Caption = Label1.Caption Then
        ctrlLabel.BackColor = Label1.BackColor
    End If
    Set ctrlLabel = Nothing
Next i
```