# How do I concatenate a string to an integer to be used as an object in a for loop?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have 12 lines like this, with 12 optionbuttons:

```
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyRow, colnum).Value = 1
End If
```

I want to replace it with

```
For i = 1 To 3 '1 question
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
Cells(emptyRow, colnum).Value = 1
End If
Next i
```

How do I write: "OptionButton"&i.Value correctly so that the i is the number and OptionButton is always the same?

Tried the solutions in comment, turned my code into this, I am getting a compile error. labelstrr is highlighted as the error.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim labelstrr As String
Dim labelnum As Integer

For j = 1 To 4 'columns 1 to 4
    For i = 1 To 3 '1 optionbutton
        labelstrr = "OptionButton" & labelnum
        If labelstrr.Value = True Then
        Cells(emptyRow, j).Value = i
        labelnum = labelnum + 1
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

Comment: try: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49502199/can-i-reference-an-object-using-a-string

Comment: or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24083717/referencing-excel-userform-control-name-value-from-string-vba

Comment: Just tried it, I get Compile error: Invalid qualifier. I edited my change in the main text.

Comment: is the button on a form or a worksheet?

Comment: The button is on a form.

Comment: you did not follow the second one `Me.Controls(labelstrr).Value = True`

Comment: In either case, the string literal `"OptionButton" & labelnum` is **not** an `OptionButton` (object) :)

Comment: Thank you scott, your second link works! It doesn't do what I expect, but no compile errors, so I will look at the rest of my code, thank you!

Comment: Note: you haven't assigned any initial value to `labelnum` so this will fail at the first iteration.

Comment: labelnum=1 a little higher, sorry, didn't include it above.